# How do I remove items from a JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, delete-operator

I am starting to learn coding with JavaScript and our teacher told us to search this site. There is no answer for my stuff so I wanted to ask. I hope that is OK, I have searched a lot of questions already but I can't find anything that is like my question.

My task is to go through my timetable and take out my two least favourite subject. This is what I have:

```
var subjects = [
  "Maths", "History", "English", "Science", "Spanish", 
  "Physical Education", "History", "English", "Science", 
  "Maths", "History", "English", "Spanish", "Physical Education"
];
```

I said I wanted to take out Spanish and History and I did that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
   if (subjects[i] == "Spanish") {
   delete subjects[i];
  }
  if (subjects[i] == "History") {
    delete subjects[i];
  }
}
```

But this says it has "empty slots" :

> Array [ "Maths", <1 empty slot>, "English", "Science", <1 empty slot>, "Physical Education", <1 empty slot>, "English", "Science", "Maths", 4 more… ]

But it should simply not be in there anymore. How can I do that?

Comment: Look at [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: we didn't talk about filter in class yet so i did it the other way. but we probably will learn that and i'll extend it then :-) thanks so much for all the cool answers. that was really so much help :-)

Comment: Good luck with your studies. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a very good resource about JS with detailed descriptions, and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found out, arrays can be "sparse" (not all indexes must have a value) and that's what you've accomplished with `delete`. You deleted the data, but left the index.

To remove the index completely, use the **[`.splice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** for this:

```js
var subjects = [
  "Maths", "History", "English", "Science", "Spanish", 
  "Physical Education", "History", "English", "Science", 
  "Maths", "History", "English", "Spanish", "Physical Education"
];


for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
   if (subjects[i] == "Spanish") {
   subjects.splice(i, 1); // At the current index, remove one element
  }
  if (subjects[i] == "History") {
    subjects.splice(i, 1);  // At the current index, remove one element
  }
}

console.log(subjects);
```

Comment: thank you so much :-) that is exactly what i tried to do :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp):

```js
var subjects = ["Maths", "History", "English", "Science", "Spanish", "Physical Education", "History", "English", "Science", "Maths", "History", "English", "Spanish", "Physical Education"];
    
function remove(arr, item) {
    for(var i = arr.length; i--;) {
        if(arr[i] === item) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
    
remove(subjects, "Spanish");
remove(subjects, "History");

document.write(subjects);
```

Output:

```
[ 'Maths',
  'English',
  'Science',
  'Physical Education',
  'English',
  'Science',
  'Maths',
  'English',
  'Physical Education' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
for (var index in subjects){
    if (subjects[index] == "Spanish"){
        subjects.splice(index,1);

    }
    if (subjects[index] == "History"){
        subjects.splice(index,1);

    } 
}
```

Comment: thank you :-) i did it similar to that in the end :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = array.indexOf('history');
if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The second parameter of splice is the number of elements to remove. Note that splice modifies the array in place and returns a new array containing the elements that have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out the delete operator just deletes the item at a location in an array. This spot is still there, but what was in that space is just empty now (arrays can have empty spaces). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements

You can use splice (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove items by index position.

```js
var subjects = [
  "Maths", "History", "English", "Science", "Spanish", 
  "Physical Education", "History", "English", "Science", 
  "Maths", "History", "English", "Spanish", "Physical Education"
];

for (var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
   if (subjects[i] === "Spanish") {
     subjects.splice(i, 1);
   }
   else if (subjects[i] === "History") {
     subjects.splice(i, 1);
   }
}

console.log(subjects);
```

Or you can use filter (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var subjects = [
  "Maths", "History", "English", "Science", "Spanish", 
  "Physical Education", "History", "English", "Science", 
  "Maths", "History", "English", "Spanish", "Physical Education"
];

var isSubjectILike = function(subject){
    return subject !== "Spanish" && subject !== "History";
};
subjects = subjects.filter(isSubjectILike);

console.log(subjects);
```

Comment: thank you :-) i did it a bit like the first example you posted. we didn't talk about "filter" in class yet so i think the first way is what the teacher is looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
var subjects = [
  "Maths", "History", "English", "Science", "Spanish", 
  "Physical Education", "History", "English", "Science", 
  "Maths", "History", "English", "Spanish", "Physical Education"
];
var index = subjects.indexOf("Spanish");
subjects = Object.assign(subjects.slice(0, index), subjects.slice(index + 1, subjects.length -1);
```

Or by using ES6 filter:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
var subjects = [
  "Maths", "History", "English", "Science", "Spanish", 
  "Physical Education", "History", "English", "Science", 
  "Maths", "History", "English", "Spanish", "Physical Education"
];
subjects = subjects.filter((value)=> value!="Spanish");
```

Comment: thank you :-) that looks so much nice and shorter than what i had!! but i used the other answer because we didn't talk about filter yet and i also don't quite know what => does

Comment: They call it arrow functions what it does is returning the evaluated expression.

Comment: oh and remember mark my answer! and let mek now if you have any other question!